# Yocto - "Nothing provides websocketpp = 0.7.0-r0 needed by websocketpp-dev-0.7.0-r0"

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am putting together a custom Linux image using Yocto. For now, it needs to include development tools and header files for numerous packages.

Thus far, this has worked perfectly fine by adding "-dev" packages as well. For example, I have added boost-dev, opencv-dev, and msgpack-c-dev. I am, however, running into errors with two recipes: (1) websocketpp_0.7.0.bb from meta-openembedded/meta-oe and (2) autobahn-cpp_18.4.1.bb which I have written. Adding -dev to either of these causes errors during the do_rootfs build phase.

- Nothing provides websocketpp = 0.7.0-r0 needed by websocketpp-dev-0.7.0-r0

The non-dev recipe seem fine and I can see the work for both recipes includes all of the expected files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most of the time -dev packages are build automatically without any further changes. Did you already checked "deploy-<package type> directory in your build output directory? It should contain -dbg, -dev by default.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve such problem, You need to create empty *websocketpp* pacakge, with using - [ALLOW_EMPTY](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ALLOW_EMPTY).

```
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for this? What makes the package empty? Is it just because they are header only libraries that don't build actual programs.

Comment: Since your `FILES_${PN}` is empty (assumedly), Yocto doesn't treat `${PN}` as a provided package. If it is a header only library, then there is likely no files to be included in `${PN}`.